# Apache conditional Header per Referer

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, nginx

I have this configuration on NgINX Server and I need to have the same rule on another Web Server that runs Apache.

**NgINX**

```
if ($http_referer !~ "^https?:\/\/.*\.sitea\.com.*|https?:\/\/.*?\.siteb\.com.*|https?:\/\/sub\.sitea\.com.*|?$") {
 add_header X-Frame-Options "DENY";
}
```

I try to use the following code, but I receive an Internal Server Error

**Apache**

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <If "%{HTTP_REFERER} !~ m#^https?:\/\/.*\.sitea\.com.*$#">
    Header append X-Frame-Options "DENY"
  </If>
</IfModule>
```

Could you anybody help to find the right way to do that?

Comment: What version of Apache?

Comment: Also, is there anything in error_log?

Comment: @MrWhite Header of any requests says only "Apache" without any version number

Comment: @DusanBajic I have no access to file log,

Comment: It sounds likes your host has imposed a more restrictive `ServerTokens` setting (security through obscurity). Anyway, the reason for checking server version is as @revo pointed out, Apache _expressions_ (as used above) are new with Apache 2.4+. The  server's error log would also have contained the details of this error.

Answer (score 2):

I find this solution that works fine with old Apache versions.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?:\/\/.*\.sitea\.com.*?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=NOFRAME:1]
Header append X-Frame-Options "DENY" env=NOFRAME
```

In this way I'm able to put `X-Frame-Options` conditionally according to a list of authorized domains.
This is a failback for old browsers that don't use Content Security Policy rules.
[You can see here the full list](https://caniuse.com/#feat=contentsecuritypolicy2).

```
Header append Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors sitea.com"
```

So modern browsers will use the CSP2 rule, older use the X-Frame-Options. Thanks to regex we could apply this option to a list of allowed domains.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}` - Presumably you should be checking against `HTTP_REFERER` instead, as in your question? As it stands (by checking against `THE_REQUEST`) your _condition_ will always be true (so your `X-Frame-Options` header will always be set).

Answer (score 0):

[Expressions](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html) came with Apache 2.4. Yours is definitely older than that.